# Теги прячутся от парсинга java/jsoup

Tags: java, безопасность, jsoup

Привет народ.

Суть вопроса: парсю сайт с помощью Jsoup. Jsoup упорно отказывается видеть id таблицы, более того, она вся скрыта (в браузере вся структура документа видна).

Данные в таблице обновляются раз в минуту. Иду по второму сценарию: сохраняю страницу локально на свой компьютер и все нормально парсится, все работает. Что это и как можно обойти проблему?

Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Comment: "Что это" - возможно (воспроизводимого примера проблемы ведь вы не привели), таблица строится с помощью JS после загрузки страницы. В таком случае нужно сохранять полностью сформированную страницу с помощью браузера (вручную или автоматически. Как это делается автоматически - не знаю), после чего парсить сохранённую версию.

Comment: приведите ссылку на сайт что парсите. так же подправьте метки, `javascript` и `java` это не одно и то же.

Comment: http://hrk.aero/onlajjn-tablo/#departure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью Jsoup **непосредственно** не получится спарсить требуемую информацию с данной страницы, потому как она генерируется динамически, насколько я понимаю, при помощи PHP.

Однако решение таки есть:

Берем любой сниффер и смотрим, что происходит в процессе загрузки страницы. Для простоты можно использовать средство, встроенное в Google Chrome: нажимаем <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, переходим во вкладку `Network`, перезагружаем страницу и *ловим* момент, в который загружается таблица. Во время загрузки таблицы во вкладке `Network` видим следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншота, таблица генерируется с помощью PHP. Далее берем URL и переходим по нему в браузере:

```
http://hrk.aero/table/ajax_tablo_new.php?lang=ru&full=1&first=1
```

И, о чудо, отображается требуемая таблица.

Далее используем полученный URL в Jsoup:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://hrk.aero/table/ajax_tablo_new.php?lang=ru&full=1&first=1").get();
        System.out.println(page);
    }
}
```

И в консоли видим HTML-код требуемой таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось лишь распарсить эту таблицу. Это, насколько я понимаю, Вы умеете.

Comment: спасибо. php не знаю буду учить. вы так это все разжевали, что прямо стыдно за себя.

Comment: @Lexis, Я тоже PHP не знаю, но тут его знать и не обязательно. Просто нужны общие знания вэба. Ничего страшного, все всегда узнают что-то новое :)